# Print the first two rows of a csv file to a standard output

Tags: python

I would like to print (stdout) the first two lines of a csv file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
afile = open('<directory>/*.csv', 'r+')
csvReader1 = csv.reader(afile)
for row in csvReader1:
    print row[0]
    print row[1]
```

however, my output using this code print the first two columns.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to print a row, but your code asks to print the first and second members of each row

Since you want to print the whole row - you can simply print it, and in addition, only read the first two

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
afile = open('<directory>/*.csv', 'r+')
csvReader1 = csv.reader(afile)
for i in range(2):
    print csvReader1.next()
```

Comment: Use `'rb'` to open files for csv in Python 2.X (see [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader)).

Comment: Suggest `next(csvReader1)` (works in both Python 2.X and 3.X).

Answer (score 6):

Generally, you can limit iterators with the [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function:

```
import itertools
for row in itertools.islice(csvReader1, 2):
    print row
```

Or by a creative use of [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for line_number, row in zip(range(2), csvReader1):
    print row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate too

```
for i, row in enumerate(csvReader1):
    if (i > 1):
        print (row)
    else:
        break
```